# Google Maps: Put Marker on Top Left of The Map

Tags: google-maps, marker, coordinate

just like the title say, I know how to add marker on specific lat,lon. Now I want to add marker and put it on top left or top right of the map. How to accomplish this using javascript api v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection

```
fromDivPixelToLatLng(pixel:Point)
```

> Computes the geographical coordinates from pixel coordinates in the
>   div that holds the draggable map.